# How to check if multiple variables are of a certain type

Tags: python

I have a program that creates four csv files in pandas. I have them encased in a try except block such that if one of the csv files fail then none of the csv files should be created. To achieve this I declare the variables before the try except block as follows

```
classes, names, extracts, cats = None, None, None, None

try:
    # create the data frames below
    ...
    ...

except Exception as e:
    # some error occurred
    print(e)


if not all(isinstance(i, pd.DataFrame) for i in [classes, names, extracts, cats]):
    # classes.to_csv(f'{output_path}classes.csv')
    # names.to_csv(f'{output_path}names.csv')
    # extracts.to_csv(f'{output_path}extracts.csv')
    # cats.to_csv(f'{output_path}cats.csv')
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

In the above code, suppose the generation of the extracts data frame fails, then the none of the css should be saved. But the code still runs the if condition and not the else part

Please help

Comment: You have the condition in the exact opposite way it's supposed to be. Just remove `not`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to create CSV files only when all four of the dataframes are created successfully, you should not use the `not` operator on the returning value of the `all` function that validates the four variables to be instances of `pd.DataFrame`.

Change:

```
if not all(isinstance(i, pd.DataFrame) for i in [classes, names, extracts, cats]):
```

to:

```
if all(isinstance(i, pd.DataFrame) for i in [classes, names, extracts, cats]):
```

Moreover, since what may prevent any of the four variables from becoming `pd.DataFrame` instances in the first place is an exception in the first `try-except` block, you can instead create your CSV files in its `else` clause, which gets executed if no exception is raised in the `try` block:

```
try:
    # create the data frames for classes, names, extracts, cats
except Exception as e:
    # some error occurred
    print(e)
else:
    classes.to_csv(f'{output_path}classes.csv')
    names.to_csv(f'{output_path}names.csv')
    extracts.to_csv(f'{output_path}extracts.csv')
    cats.to_csv(f'{output_path}cats.csv')
```